# Proof that a limit of $x$ goes to $a$ exists for every real $a$.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I want to proof that $\lim \limits_{x \to a} 7x^2$ exists for every real a, using the epsilon-delta approach.

I know that I need to use $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, but I don't have an $L$ in this situation. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Try $L = 7a^2$, the function value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L=7a^2$. Then $|7x^2-L|=|7x^2-7a^2|=7|x+a||x-a|$. If $|x-a|<1$, then $$|x+a|\leqslant|x-a|+2|a|<1+2|a|.$$So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon{7(1+2|a|)}\right\}$, and then$$|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl|7x^2-L\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: I think $|x+a| \le |x| + |a| \le |x-a| + |2a| \lt 1+ 2|a|.$ Because as per your criteria if we put $x=\frac 34$ and $a=\frac 14$ then $|\frac 34 + \frac 14| \le |\frac 34- \frac 14|+|\frac 14|$, which is not possible.

Comment: @Mathmore Thanks. I've edited my answer. If you find another error, please tell me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't understand why you take |x-a|<1, where does the 1 come from

Comment: @TheCodingWombat If you want me to take another number greater than $0$ instead of $1$, tell me which number and I will solve your problem using that number.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can also see how it would be solved with other numbers than 1, but what made you decide to choose 1? Was the 1 the best number to be picked here, or would a smaller number, or rather a bigger number have been better?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat If another number would have been better, I would have picked it. But why $1$? Because it is the simpler choice of a number greater than $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay thank you, so the number had to be close to zero, and for simplicity you chose the closes integer. I get it now.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.